# GAE Java Facebook server authentication double call

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I am having a weird issue. I created an application on Google App Engine and have a Login with Facebook button on it, for which I am doing server side authentication.

I give the redirect_url, and facebook was calling the URL correctly with no issues. The session parameters that I set were being retrieved on the redirect call and everything was working fine.

Yesterday, I got a domain on godaddy and mapped it to my appspot account using google apps. Now when I click on Facebook login, I am getting two calls on the redirect uri, the first one carries the session varaibles and the session one doesn't. I am not very familiar with domain mapping and followed the steps on Google Apps.

Can anyone help me in the right direction on this.

Comment: I cannot help you, but I am interested in your implementation of Facebook authentication .. Can you please share your code?

Comment: Thanks Michele, my code is pretty straightforward picked up from the questions posted on this forum and in google app engine tutorial website. I have a login button that calls a custom action class, in which I do a response.sendRedirect() to facebook graph api with redirect uri as another action method call. I am using struts by the way

Comment: Anyone else have any other ideas? This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers bsautner and Michele. I finally figured out the issue. I have google ads on my website. The google ads was trying to parse the URL content and creating a second request for every request that I create. After removing the google ads, I get a single callback with session values retained. It all works now. The final output is this website - [www.imagecrashers.com](http://www.imagecrashers.com). I will be glad for any suggestions from the gurus here, regarding layout or api calls simplification. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 0):

it's a little out of date, but i documented some GAE to Facebook gotchas here: 
http://javagwt.blogspot.com/2010/08/facebook-apps-on-app-engine-without-any.html

It may also help to read about naked domain mapping with godaddy, to make sure you're not getting bounced around. Even though you are mapped to your domain through google apps, you can try to put the redirect URL for facebook as yourappid.appspot.com - the redirect URL you provide, and the one in your facebook app settings must match.

My app, nimbits.com writes to facebook from GAE all of the time - the code is on github under server/facebook

https://github.com/bsautner/com.nimbits/tree/master/nimbits-tds/src/com/nimbits/server